# Other tax modules that are reputable besides AvaTax

Tags: extensions, tax, third-party-module, taxes

Can you guys give me some ideas on what else is out there? I've searched through the market but it all seems pretty meager in terms of other avenues to go down.

AvaTax is really expensive. Currently, we are just uploading an excel file occasionally which is very easy but would like something automated.

Answer (score 2):

[TaxJar](https://www.taxjar.com) and [Vertex](https://www.vertexinc.com/) are both premier Magento technology partners with sales tax extensions.

Speaking on behalf of TaxJar, we provide free sales tax calculations for Magento merchants and [paid subscriptions](https://www.taxjar.com/pricing/) for automated reporting and filing. Calculations are made directly through our [sales tax API](https://developers.taxjar.com/api/reference/), but we also have a backup rates feature that periodically imports zip-based tax rates into Magento's rate tables in case our API becomes unavailable.

If you're interested, here's some resources to get started:

- [TaxJar Magento 2 Extension](https://marketplace.magento.com/taxjar-module-taxjar.html) ([GitHub](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento2-extension))
- [TaxJar Magento 2 Extension Guide](https://www.taxjar.com/guides/integrations/magento2/)

Comment: Thanks, I've installed it as of today. It looks very intuitive.